# How to add time column to the time stamp column in Vertica ? (or another db's)

Tags: sql, vertica

I have two columns like that:

ihour (type=HH:mm:ss)
06:40:41

its (type=timestamp)
2020-12-10 00:00:00.000000

I want to add ihour to the its column and have a single column showing me date and time.
How can I do this in Vertica? If you know how to do it in another db's, I would be happy because at least I could learn the way that I should follow in Vertica.

Comment: In Postgres you could do `timestamp_column::date + time_column` (assuming `time_column` is of type `time`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name cool, it worked in Vertica also. Thx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the time to INTERVAL, and add the two:

```
WITH
indata(ihour,its) AS (
  SELECT TIME '06:40:41', TIMESTAMP '2020-12-10 00:00:00.000000'
)
SELECT
  its + ihour::INTERVAL(6) AS timesum
FROM indata;
timesum
2020-12-10 06:40:41
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below using TIMESTAMPADD()

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD (DATE(its), 0, (SELECT TRUNC(ihour, 'HH:MM:SS')))
```